# Subset dataframe after first encounter of a specific string

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, subset, tidyr

I have a dataframe of the following format and I would like to extract or subset the data frame such that I have only activities prior to the first `funding` activity in each project:

```
 project<- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B','B', 'C', 'C')
 activity<- c('kickoff','funding', 'delivery', 'kickoff','kickoff','funding','kickoff', 'kickoff','delivery')

 df<- data.frame(project,activity)
```

I am expecting an output as follows:

```
 project   activity 
 A         kickoff
 B         kickoff
 B         kickoff
 C         kickoff
 C         delivery
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr`:

```
df %>%
    group_by(project) %>%
    dplyr::filter(cummin(activity != "funding") == 1)
```

yields:

```
# project activity
# <fctr>   <fctr>
# 1       A  kickoff
# 2       B  kickoff
# 3       B  kickoff
# 4       C  kickoff
# 5       C delivery
```

`base R`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dff, dff$project), function(x) {
    x[cummin(x$activity != "funding") == 1, ]
}))
```

yields:

```
# project activity
# A       kickoff 
# B       kickoff 
# B       kickoff 
# C       kickoff 
# C       delivery
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!df[, .I[.I >= first(.I[activity == 'funding'])], by = project]$V1]
```

> ```
>    project activity
> 1:       A  kickoff
> 2:       B  kickoff
> 3:       B  kickoff
> 4:       C  kickoff
> 5:       C delivery
> ```

#### Explanation

Within each `project` group, we look for the indices of the first appearance of `"funding"` in column `activity` and all subsequent rows:

```
df[, .I[.I >= first(.I[activity == 'funding'])], by = project]
```

> ```
>    project V1
> 1:       A  2
> 2:       A  3
> 3:       B  6
> 4:       B  7
> ```

In `data.table`, `.I` is a special symbol which holds the row location in `df`. The second subsetting `.I[.I >= first(.I[activity == 'funding'])]` is required because `which(.I >= first(.I[activity == 'funding']))` would return only the row locations *within* the group but not within `df`.

Now, we have indentified the rows which should *not be displayed*. Therefore, we get the final result by *excluding* these row numbers:

```
df[!df[, .I[.I >= first(.I[activity == 'funding'])], by = project]$V1]
```

---

In case there are date information available - and I bet there is a `date` column when dealing with projects and activities - we can follow a suggestion by @Frank and do an *anti non-equi join* using the date column:

```
# create sample date with date column
project<- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B','B', 'C', 'C')
activity<- c('kickoff','funding', 'delivery', 'kickoff','kickoff','funding','kickoff', 'kickoff','delivery')
date <- (as.Date ("2017-10-02") + c(1,4,7,2,5,8,11,3,6))
df <- data.frame(project,activity, date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df[order(df$date), ]
```

> ```
>   project activity       date
> 1       A  kickoff 2017-10-03
> 4       B  kickoff 2017-10-04
> 8       C  kickoff 2017-10-05
> 2       A  funding 2017-10-06
> 5       B  kickoff 2017-10-07
> 9       C delivery 2017-10-08
> 3       A delivery 2017-10-09
> 6       B  funding 2017-10-10
> 7       B  kickoff 2017-10-13
> ```

```
# anti non-equi join
setDT(df)[!df[activity == 'funding', first(date), by = project], on = .(project, date >= V1)]
```

> ```
>    project activity       date
> 1:       A  kickoff 2017-10-03
> 2:       B  kickoff 2017-10-04
> 3:       B  kickoff 2017-10-07
> 4:       C  kickoff 2017-10-05
> 5:       C delivery 2017-10-08
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Some other alternatives with the `data.table` package:

**1) with `Reduce`:**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[!Reduce('+', activity == 'funding', accumulate = TRUE)], project]$V1]
```

**2) with `cummax`:**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[!cummax(activity == 'funding')], project]$V1]
```

**3) with `pmax`:**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!df[, pmax(.I, .I[activity == 'funding']), by = project]$V1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cumsum` to track whether for each project, a row takes place before or after funding:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(project) %>%
  mutate(before.funding = cumsum(activity == "funding") == 0) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(before.funding) %>%
  select(-before.funding)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  project activity
   <fctr>   <fctr>
1       A  kickoff
2       B  kickoff
3       B  kickoff
4       C  kickoff
5       C delivery
```